# Merging multiple CVS files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am struggling with merging multiple .csv files using pandas.

All of the files have the
same structure as presented below, where 'UniqueColumn' varies for every csv, and column "Name" is same for every csv but they are not sorted in the same way:

```
csv1:
Name, UniqueColumnA
testName, DataA
...

csv2:
Name, UniqueColumnB
testName, DataB
...
```

etc.

Desired merged csv file would look like this:

```
Name, UniqueColumnA, UniqueColumnB, UniqueColumnC
testName, DataA, DataB, DataC
```

I've tried to use the following code:

```
files = glob.glob(r'pathname*.csv')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=['Name']) for f in files])
df.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

But the output was

```
testName, DataA
testName, DataB
...
```

I'm not very much familiar with Python, especially with pandas so I would really appreciate a helping hand here

Comment: Do you need `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=['Name']) for f in files], axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are duplicate indices, you need to tell pandas how to treat them, in your case, you want an `inner join` so the following should work for you:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Name') for f in files], join='inner', axis=1)
```